# How Do I Print Out The Sum Of A Palindrome in Java?

Tags: java, loops

I am having trouble printing out the sum of a palindrome without using ant string methods and only using mathematical methods. I have figured out how to calculate the sum and everything but when I try to print out the sum it gives me a list of all of the numbers. For example, for the number 11, the output is this 
1
3
6
10
15
21
28
36
45
55
66

I want to figure out how to only print out the last number, 66, which is the sum of the numbers 1 to 11 and also how to make the program print out "1 to 11" since the numbers are user inputted using the scanner method. Below my code I have included what my output should look like. Thank you so much!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {
    public static void main (String args []) {
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer > 0:");
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        int palindrome=keyboard.nextInt();
        int palindrome1=palindrome;
        int num;
        int sum;

        int rev=0;
        if (palindrome<=0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you must enter an integer greater than zero.");
        }


        while (palindrome!=0) {
            rev=rev*10 + palindrome % 10;
            palindrome/=10;
            System.out.println("the integer "+palindrome1+ " is a palindrome");
        }
        if (palindrome1==rev) {
            System.out.println("palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not");
        }
        num=1;
        sum=0;
        while (num<=palindrome1) {
            sum=sum+num;
            num++;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

The output should look like this:

Please enter an integer > 0: 11
The integer 11 is a palindrome.
The sum of the numbers from 1 to 11 is 66

Answer (score 3):

You could always use the common math rule which describes the sum of a number from 0 to n:

[image]

This is also simpler as you don't have to really worry about accumulating the values in a loop.

In your scenario, all you'd need to do in order to print the value out would be to compute this.

Reduced, it'd be:

```
System.out.println((n*n) - n))/2);
```

Alternatively, if you only want to print the last item that you're adding, then only print after the loop has completed.

Comment: Why did you "simplify" that equation into an expression that uses floating-point rather than integer math?

Comment: @Elogent:  Well...I could leave the figuring out of getting that value from a float to an int to the reader...

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

You may simplify the sum of consecutive integers using the rule stated above by Makoto.

Naming your integer variable 'palindrome' before confirming that it is a palindrome may be confusing.

The statement on line 24 appears to be incorrectly placed.

You have indicated that you don't want the sum to be printed each loop iteration, so you might want to move the last println outside that while loop.

Answer (score -1):

Change the last while loop to this:

```
while (num<=palindrome1){

sum=sum+num;
System.out.println(num);
num++;

    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Comment: "The output should look like this:..The sum of the numbers from 1 to 11 is 66"